# How to disable button with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've tried everything!

```
$('#m-button').button('disabled')
$('#m-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
$('#m-button').prop('disabled', 'disabled')
$('#m-button').attr('disabled', 'true')
$('#m-button').prop('disabled', 'true')
$('#m-button').attr('enabled', 'false')

<button id="m-button" class="btn" type="button" >Add Note</button>
```

It stays enabled though.  What's the proper way to disable a `<button>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#m-button').prop('disabled', true)
```

without quotes around `true`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MYv3j/)**

Per the jQuery docs on [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from around `true` and use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), like follows:

`$('#m-button').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$('#m-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

all you need is just to add `disabled` attribute to your button.